# How to cite authors with a single letter last name such as Gordon D particularly in scientific journals?

Tags: citing, nameauth

In this example, the author's full legal name is "Gordon D", first name = Gordon, last name = D. How does one cite this name when mostly the last name is used for citation purposes?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se.  I'm not sure that this is really a LaTeX question though. There's no problem with having a single letter last name as far as `bibtex` is concerned, and any field who would likely be citing such an author is probably aware of the name. So although the output will give journal editors fits, there's no technical problem to doing it. If the problem is with the journal editors, there are ways to construct an alternative label for citing, e.g. the `shortauthor` field if using `biblatex`. I can add an answer showing that if it would be helpful.